# How to get a list of existing student names in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Django rest framework, I want to get a list of the
student first names(only) when it is existed. can anyone help me?

In my `models.py`

```py
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.city}->{self.street}->{self.name}"

class Student(models.Model):
    school_id = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

In my `serializers.py`:

```py
class StudentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['first_name']
   

class SchoolSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    is_existing_student = = serializers.BooleanField()
    student = StudentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = ['is_existing_student','student']
```

In my `views.py`:

```py
class schoolViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SchoolSerializer
    queryset = School.objects.all()
```

In this picture you can see how it should look like
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR8cN.png

Comment: So you have to write a view, which will return the students.

Comment: you want all the student or just one student if he/she exist?

Comment: I want only the first name of the already registered students to be shown in a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `values()` method or `values-list()` method
so you can do something like

```
Student.objects.values_list('first_name')
```

or

```
Student.objects.values('first_name')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Answer (score 0):

try adding a student view in your views.py then use values() method

```
class StudentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
    queryset = Student.objects.values('first_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you define on first_name model field, i.e null=False, blank=False. It means the field cannot be empty.

```py
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
```

Which means all your models call will always have first_name required

Meanwhile, if you still want to be sure that your query returns items with first_name, do this

```py
queryset = School.objects.exclude(student__first_name=None)
```